# How to convert a byte array to a png image

Tags: ruby, png

I want to convert a byte string from Ice server to a png as frequent as 30 times per second. I use `chunky_png` gem with this code:

```
data = @@cprx.getImageData()
width= data.description.width   
height = data.description.height
png = ChunkyPNG::Image.new(width,height, ChunkyPNG::Color::TRANSPARENT)
pixeles = data.pixelData.bytes.to_a
k=0
for i in 0..height-1
  for j in 0..width-1
    png[j,i]=ChunkyPNG::Color.rgb(pixeles[k],pixeles[k+1],pixeles[k+2])
    k=k+3
  end
end
image = png.to_data_url
```

I create an image and I give values pixel by pixel. But it is too slow. I would like to know if there is a faster method.

Comment: Is it 30 _different_ images a second? Is caching an option?

Comment: Can you maybe fork 4-8 processes to keep all your CPUs/cores busy and send images to them in a round-robin fashion? Or does each image need knowledge of previous/next one for movement detection or somesuch?

Comment: I try to send video sending 30 images per second (could be less , maybe 25 or something). -yes the images are diferent between them and I am not going to use them for movement detection by the moment although it is for a surveillance proyect.

Comment: If you are trying to achieve a video-effect, the `png` is most probably the wrong solution. Moreover, at that kind of speed requirement (and maybe multiple clients?) you should probably use some other language than ruby to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Take a look at `opencv` Ruby bindings: E.g. http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/o/opencv-0.0.6/OpenCV/CvCapture.html to receive a video stream. The OpenCV library includes routines that you will likely find very useful for your project.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I have solved the problem with the method from_rgb_stream. Besides there is a library equivalent to chunky_png called oily_png that is faster thanks to a c++ core. My code currently looks like:

```
def ice_camera
    status = 0
    ic = nil
    if session[:conected2] == nil
        arguments= ["--Ice.Config=cameraview.cfg"]
        ic = Ice::initialize(arguments)
        base = ic.propertyToProxy("Cameraview.Camera.Proxy")
        cprx = Jderobot::CameraPrx::checkedCast(base)
        session[:conected2] = true
        thr1 = Thread.new do
            @@mutex = Mutex.new
            while true do
                puts "11111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
                data = cprx.getImageData()
                png = ChunkyPNG::Canvas.from_rgb_stream(data.description.width, data.description.height, data.pixelData)
                @@mutex.synchronize do
                    @@image=png.to_data_url
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```